# Getting initial window property from Remix App

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

Im wanting to make a useMediaQuery hook for my remix app where I can hide/show components on depending on the screen size.

Obviously since remix renders everything on the server I don't have easy access to window to figure out the initial screen size. I can get it working via a useEffect to get the window object but on the initial load the it will always return false and then change to true if the window is in the valid state. Even if I change the initial state to true the same issue would occur.

```js
export const useMediaQuery = (minWidth: number) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    windowWidth: 0,
    isDesiredWidth: false,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentWindowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    const isDesiredWidth = currentWindowWidth < minWidth;
    setState({
      windowWidth: currentWindowWidth,
      isDesiredWidth: isDesiredWidth,
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const resizeHandler = () => {
      const currentWindowWidth = window.innerWidth;
      const isDesiredWidth = currentWindowWidth < minWidth;
      setState({ windowWidth: currentWindowWidth, isDesiredWidth });
    };
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeHandler);
  }, [minWidth, state.windowWidth]);

  return state.isDesiredWidth;
};
```

Just wondering if anyone has built anything similar or has any advice on how I could get this working for the initial load of the app.

I also know that I could just hide the elements via css but my app would still be rendering the components and there are some with quite a bit of complexity which could cause unnecessary re-renders, even if they are hidden.

Comment: Havent implemented such a hook, but I have used Mantine's implementation of it. [Maintine's use-media-query hook](https://github.com/mantinedev/mantine/blob/master/src/mantine-hooks/src/use-media-query/use-media-query.ts). Perhaps this may help.